# Javascript - cannot stop link from loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link element (actually, all the links of a certain class) to which I have bound a click event.

Here's an example link element:

```
<a id="2" class="paginationclick" style="cursor: pointer;" href="">2</a>
```

And here's the binding:

```
$(".paginationclick").click(function(e) {
    displayAccountSearchResults(e);

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
});
```

displayAccountSearchResults(e) executes fine but then the page reloads.  I do not want the page to reload.  Why isn't stopPropagation / cancelBubble working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `e.preventDefault`

```
$(".paginationclick").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    displayAccountSearchResults(e);

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I love you.  That did it!  :)

Comment: Sorry.. i m married :) Glad it helped.